# Tensorflow multi-dimensional indexing by another tensor

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, tensorflow

Say, I have a rank-k tensor X of shape [n1, n2, ..., nk] and a rank-(k-1) tensor IDX of shape [n2, n3, ..., nk], where IDX has the same shape as the last (k-1) dimensions of X. The entries of IDX are all integers in [0, n1). I would like to fetch some values from X where the first dimension positions are specified by IDX while the other dimensions are iterated all through.

Example:

```
X = tf.constant([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6],
                 [7,8], [9,10],[11,12]]) # 2 x 3 x 2 tensor
IDX = tf.constant([[1,0], [1,1], [0,1]]) #     3 x 2 tensor
...
# would like to get [[7,2],[9,10],[5,12]]
```

How to achieve this in Tensorflow efficiently? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the note for `choose`?

> Notes
>
> To reduce the chance of misinterpretation, even though the following
>   "abuse" is nominally supported, `choices` should neither be, nor be
>   thought of as, a single array, i.e., the outermost sequence-like container
>   should be either a list or a tuple.

That is, they want you to treat it like:

```
In [432]: list(X)
Out[432]: [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])]
In [433]: np.choose(IDX,list(X))
Out[433]: array([3, 6])
```

The indexing equivalent is:

```
In [436]: X[IDX,np.arange(2)]
Out[436]: array([3, 6])
```

`choose` also has some `mode` options.

The docs also say it's equivalent to (minus these mode issues):

```
np.choose(a,c) == np.array([c[a[I]][I] for I in ndi.ndindex(a.shape)])
```

Another nuance with `choose`.  It can't work with more than 32 choices.

```
In [440]: np.choose(IDX,np.ones((33,2)))
...
ValueError: Need at least 1 and at most 32 array objects.

In [442]: np.ones((33,2))[IDX,np.arange(2)]
Out[442]: array([ 1.,  1.])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realized that I misunderstood the np.choose() function. Now the question is how to achieve what I want efficiently in Tensorflow. Any comments?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is about tensorflow, not numpy

Comment: @dopexxx, the original question asked specifically about `np.choose`, and whether there was a `tensorflow` equivalent.  Understanding `choose` is relevant to finding an equivalent.  The answers were not changed in response to a major edit in the original question.  If you have something to contribute, feel free to add your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `np.choose()` in a python function and embed it in your tensorflow graph with `tf.py_func()`. But you would also define gradient for your function if you would like automatic gradient computation of your graph for training to be available for you. Defining gradient for `np.choose()` might be very tricky task I suppose, if actually being solvable at all.